# How to stop Application in pepper remotely

Tags: python-2.7, pepper, choregraphe

By following the documentation of NAOqi, I can start my application by doing the following command
tabService.showWebview("http://" + ip + "/apps/"  + uid + "/index.html")

Now I want to terminate/stop this by remotely by similar way.

Does anybody know this?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: I want to terminate current service like ALTextToSpeech service remotely via python script from my local system when the application runs in the pepper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you are starting your application by calling showWebView().
You just display the website on the tablet.

Now I see several options for you, depending on what you actually want:

1. You want to terminate your application then ALBehaviorManager API offers the method [stopBehavior](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/core/albehaviormanager-api.html#ALBehaviorManagerProxy::stopBehavior__ssCR)
2. You want to hide the website then ALTabletService API offers the method [hide](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/core/altabletservice-api.html#ALTabletService::hide)
3. You want to terminate a specific service then you can have look into ServiceManager API method [stopService](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/core/servicemanager-api.html#qi::ServiceManager::stopService__ssCR)
4. You want to stop Pepper from speaking ALTextToSpeech API offers the function [stopAll](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/audio/altexttospeech-api.html?highlight=stopall#ALTextToSpeechProxy::stopAll) e.g.:

> import naoqi from naoqi
>   import ALProxy
>   tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech",IP, 9559)
>   tts.stopAll()

5. You want to stop Pepper from listening and responding, you can deactivate the topic with ALDialog API method [deactivateTopic](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/dialog/aldialog-api.html#ALDialogProxy::deactivateTopic__ssCR)

Comment: Hi I tried with stopBehavior but it restart the application automatically even though I used the sleep time more. I have not tried with hide.

Comment: what do you mean by "sleep time more" ?

Comment: import time      then time.sleep(50)  This is the sleep time I am talking about.